# center a div-based popup window on the screen from iframe

Tags: javascript, css, html, iframe, position

I have an iframe, and from the iframe I am calling a javascript code to display a small window (actually a div tag).  The window should be displayed on the center of the screen independent from the iframe.  I saw some codes for dialog box (e.g., alert box), but could not find a way to center a div-based custom window.  Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Show us what you've tried/have.

Comment: It is not possible to place content outside of the iframe. It is possible if both pages (the page and the page from the iframe) are from the same domain.

Comment: yes, they are from the same domain.  Or, is there a way to position the div content in the iframe, so that it will look like it is in the center of the page?